# Сборка проекта под android утилитой gradle

Tags: android, c++, gradle, sfml, apk

У меня есть два приложения. При сборке проекта утилитой gradle через консоль, собранное приложение ставится в устройство поверх старого и тем самым перезаписывает его.Я пробовал ставить отдельно apk файл, но результат тот-же.
Ну и вопросы: как сделать так, чтобы можно было установить несколько приложений на устройство? И почему так происходит?

Comment: может они называются одинаково?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, ответ был почти верный. Проблема заключается в том, что каждый созданный apk-файл использует уникальный ApplicationID, например: `"com.example.myapp"`. Он находится в `build.gradle`.
 Достаточно изменить его имя, и проблема решена.

**Итого:**

1. Заходим в файл `build.gradle`
2. Находим строчку `applicationId`
3. Изменяем название
4. Пересобираем проект